# No logro hacer que un pdf sea firmado con sha-256 en c# usando iTextSharp - Algoritmo Especificado no es VALIDO

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, firma-digital, sha256

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación en windows forms la cual me permita firmar un documento pdf usando sha-256, logré hacerla funcionar usando sha-1 pero no pasó lo mismo con sha-256. e buscado por varios foros e intentado varias maneras de hacerlo funcionar pero no tuve éxito alguno. el método que estoy usando es el siguiente y como lo comenté funciona solo para sha-1 y md5, pero quisiera que funcione para sha-256.

```
public void Firmar(string rutaDocumentoSinFirma, string rutaDocumentoFirmado, X509Certificate2 cert, string rutaLogo,string posx , string posy, string pag)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(rutaDocumentoSinFirma))
    using (var writer = new FileStream(rutaDocumentoFirmado, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, writer, '\0', null, true))
    {
        var signature = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        signature.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;

        signature.Reason = "Soy autor del documento";
        //signature.ReasonCaption = "Tipo de firma";
        signature.Location = "";
        signature.SignDate = DateTime.Now;

        signature.Acro6Layers = true;

        var bcCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);


        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] {cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData)};


        PdfSignature objSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
        objSignature.Date = new PdfDate(signature.SignDate);
        signature.CryptoDictionary = objSignature;

        string nombre = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(bcCert).GetField("CN");
        string razSocial = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(bcCert).GetField("O");
        string cargo = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(bcCert).GetField("T");
        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;

        signature.Layer2Text =
            "" +   
            "Firmado Digitalmente por: " + nombre + "\n" +
            "Razón Social: " + razSocial + "\n" +
            "Cargo: " + cargo + "\n" +
            "Fecha: " + fecha;

        signature.Layer2Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 5);

        //valores 
        Int32 posicionx = Convert.ToInt32(posx);
        Int32 posiciony = Convert.ToInt32(posy);
        Int32 pagina = Convert.ToInt32(pag);

        //***************
        Image img = Image.GetInstance(rutaLogo);

        signature.SignatureGraphic = img;
        //***************
        //X - Y - ancho - alto
        signature.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
        
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(posicionx, posiciony, 210 + posicionx, 34+ posiciony);
        signature.SetVisibleSignature(rect, pagina, null);

        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-256");
        
        var signatureChain = certificado.Chain;
        var standard = CryptoStandard.CADES;

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signature, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, standard);

    }
}
```

Este código recibe el primer certificado con llave privada que encuentre en la pc(solo a modo de prueba, luego será una lista donde se podrá elegir un certificado), luego el mismo windows hace aparecer la ventana para colocar la clave del certificado y si es correcta firma el documento. Probé en cambiar donde dice SHA-1 a SHA-256 y me lanza el error "Algoritmo Especificado no Valido", soy realmente nuevo en este tema de las firmas digitales, es por eso que por favor pido su apoyo con este tema, adicionalmente dejo el link donde se puede descargar el código fuente del programa para que sea mas entendible. Saludos y gracias.

Fuentes Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fSGLs75xeuDBLI-WQjBaf0TYLWmvOL0X/view?usp=sharing